# I'm not sure what it means by invalid token

Tags: python, token

I'm not sure what it means by invalid token. This is the error log

```
runfile('C:/Users/evilq/Documents/PBPKmodel2.py', wdir='C:/Users/evilq/Documents')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\evilq\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-68126a0125a6>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/evilq/Documents/PBPKmodel2.py', wdir='C:/Users/evilq/Documents')
  File "C:\Users\evilq\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\evilq\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/evilq/Documents/PBPKmodel2.py", line 120
    ABrn     = y[01] # Amount of PTU in Brain              ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

This is the code:

```
def CafPBPK(y,t):

# Amount Variables

AArt     = y[00] # Amount of PTU in Arteries
ABrn     = y[01] # Amount of PTU in Brain
#   AMsl     = y[02]; # Amount of PTU in Muscle
ARap     = y[02] # Amount of PTU in Rapidly Perfused Tissues
ASlw     = y[03] # Amount of PTU in Slowly Perfused Tissues
AFat     = y[04] # Amount of PTU in Fat/Adipose Tissue
#   ASkn     = y[06]; # Amount of PTU in Skin
#   AFKid    = y[07]; # Amount of PTU Filtered in Kidney
AKid     = y[05] # Amount of PTU in Kidney
AMLiv    = y[06] # Amount of PTU Metabolized in Liver
ALiv     = y[07] # Amount of PTU in Liver



  'This would be the dosing information/ the concentration it the organs'
  # Concentrations
   CArt     = AArt /VBld  # Concentration of PTU in Arteries
  CBrn     = ABrn /VBrn  # Concentration of PTU in Brain
  #   CMsl     = AMsl /VMsl;  # Concentration of PTU in Muscle
  CSlw     = ASlw /VSlw  # Concentration of PTU in Slowly Perfused Tissues
  CRap     = ARap /VRap  # Concentration of PTU in Rapidly Perfused Tissues
  CFat     = AFat /VFat  # Concentration of PTU in Fat/Adipose Tissue
 #   CSkn     = ASkn /VSkn;  # Concentration of PTU in Skin
  CKid     = AKid /VKid  # Concentration of PTU in Kidney
  CLiv     = ALiv /VLiv  # Concentration of PTU in Liver
  #   CGutT    = AGutT/VGut;  # Concentration of PTU in Gut Tissue


CVen  = ((QBrn * (CBrn/PBrn)) 
      +  (QSlw * (CSlw/PSlw)) 
      +  (QRap * (CRap/PRap)) 
      +  (QFat * (CFat/PFat)) 
      +  (QKid * (CKid/PKid))
      +  (QLiv * (CLiv/PLiv)))/QTot
 # 
 #Ingestion
 RAArt = QTot * (CVen - CArt + CIng)
 RABrn = QBrn * (CArt - CBrn/PBrn)
RAFat = QFat * (CArt - CFat/PFat)
RASlw = QSlw * (CArt - CSlw/PSlw)
RARap = QRap * (CArt - CRap/PRap)
RAKid = QKid * (CArt - CKid/PKid)

RAMLiv = (Vmax * CLiv)/(Km + CLiv)
RALiv = QLiv * (CArt - CLiv/PLiv) - RAMLiv

dydt = [0]*8
dydt[0] = RAArt
dydt[1] = RABrn
dydt[2] = RARap
dydt[3] = RASlw
dydt[4] = RAFat
dydt[5] = RAKid
dydt[6] = RAMLiv
dydt[7] = RALiv

return dydt
```

Comment: Why `y[00]`? Why not `y[0]` and so on?

Comment: Because I got confused, but thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`01` is invalid. The integer number one in python is represented like this: `1`

In python 2 starting with a 0 meant octal notation, but in python 3 it was deprecated to prevent mistakes. `0o1` is octal and `1` is decimal, `01` is syntax error now.